# Convert String^ to const char*

Tags: c++, string, stl, c++-cli

Haven't used Windows Form in a very long time and this is my first time using it in C++.

And so it's the first time I've encountered the use of ^ after data types and class objects, for example:

```
Void Form1::btnConvert_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

spooky stuff.

I'm trying to call a function which requires a long pointer to constant string, so const char* or LPCSTR.

```
const char* cPath = txtBoxPath->Text.c_str();
```

The problem is when I try to convert from string^ I receive the error:

```
error C2228: left of '.c_str' must have class/struct/union
          type is 'System::String ^'
          did you intend to use '->' instead?
```

So, now I'm in a bit of a pickle. Any suggestions? Maybe educate me a bit on this ^ symbol, cause I don't seem to find anything on it when googling.

Comment: Nothing to do with "Forms", but much to do with C++/CLI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `System::String` to a `std::string` via:

```
// Requires:
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

auto str = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(txtBoxPath->Text);
```

Once you have a `std::string`, then `c_str()` will provide you the `const char*`:

```
const char* cPath = str.c_str();
```

Note that you can also use `Marshal` to do the conversion directly, ie:

```
IntPtr tmpHandle = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(txtBoxPath->Text);
char *cPath = static_cast<char*>(tmpHandle.ToPointer());

// use cPath

Marshal::FreeHGlobal(tmpHandle); // Don't use cPath after this...
```

Answer (score 0):

The ^ character denotes a managed pointer (or reference). txtBoxPath::Text is a reference of type System::String. You'll need to de-reference it to use the dot operator or just use ->.

For the System::String^ to char* try the following:

```
char* cPath = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(txtBoxPath->Text).ToPointer();
```

Comment: This doesn't address converting to a `const char*`, though.

Comment: @ReedCopsey you're correct - I've added a proper example to answer the question correctly - thanks, I got distracted and submitted early.

Comment: Note that this is a memory leak.  You need to keep the handle, and properly free it via `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`.  See my answer for details.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting a couple errors though :x I'll read up on Marshal quickly now.

error C2653: 'Marshal' : is not a class or namespace name
error C2228: left of '.ToPointer' must have class/struct/union

Comment: @ReedCopsey yes, that's correct. I was making (maybe bad) assumption the developer would realize he needed to manage his unmanaged memory.

Comment: @Anthony You'd need to include `using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices` to use `Marshal`, but note that it's a lot more work than just using the built-in `marshal_as` options in my answer, since you must also free with Marshal.